# F#: how to generate a list range with descending elements?

Tags: f#, range, intervals

[1..4] could help to generate

```
[1;2;3;4]
```

But I wish to generate a range like this:

```
[10;8;6;4;2]
```

How to use range semantics to achieve this(interval+descending)? Is a "for" loop mandatory in this case?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
[10 .. -2 .. 2] ;;
// val it : int list = [10; 8; 6; 4; 2]
```

The value in the middle specifies the interval.